# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, infragistics

Error when I am trying to display the form designer.

Here is error image :
[image: Error Image in Visual Studio 2008]

**Text Image:**

```
Instances of this error (1)  

1.   Hide Call Stack 

at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlingConfigurationView.GetExceptionPolicyData(String policyName)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyCustomFactory.CreateObject(IBuilderContext context, String name, IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ConfigurationReflectionCache reflectionCache)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.ConfiguredObjectStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)  

Help with this error  

MSDN Help   


Forum posts about this error  

Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error
```

**Here is Source Code:**
[image: Source Code Image]

What's wrong with my coding? I use Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Comment: Form are contains Infragistics Controls.

Comment: does the suggestion here answer your question: http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16/p/4461/18341.aspx#18341

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying one or more controls that require data to function correctly and you haven't set up that data for the designer.

You have two choices:

1. If it's your control you can add a check to see if it's in design mode. Wrap any calls to databases etc. which won't be set up in design mode with these tests:

   [Component.DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c58hb4bw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for WinForms

   [GetIsInDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx) for WPF

   [DesignModeEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.designmode.designmodeenabled.aspx) for WinRT

   [IsInDesignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesigntool%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for Silverlight
2. Set up some design data. Exactly how you do this will depend on the control.